# Is ICMP protocol widely used in real world?

Tags: icmp

Is the ICMP protocol generally used in real world networking configurations ?

- If yes, what are some real world examples that make use of this protocol.

In addition, I see that the ICMP echo requests (type 0 / 8) are a **must filter** within an organization be it small or large, and the main reason is to avoid foot printing of the network by potential malicious persons.

- In reality does this must be mandatory for a network and does it happen ? I see large sites as google, yahoo and other sites not blocking ICMP echo messages.

Regards

Comment: ICMP echo is one small part of ICMP that is an integral part of IP.

Comment: They do block *some* ICMP messages.  It's a tradeoff between usability and security.  You may block echo requests inbound, but allow echo replies inbound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completely filtering ICMP, as some people do, is a very bad idea. It is designed to give feedback to applications and users. For example, a network or destination host that does not exist can generate an ICMP error message. It is an integral part of IP, and is used for PMTUD. See *[RFC 792, Internet Message Control Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792)*.

IPv6 relies heavily on ICMP, and there is *[RFC 4890, Recommendations for Filtering ICMPv6 Messages in Firewalls](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4890)* that explains what should and should not be blocked for ICMPv6.